# How to make css where arrows overlap with eachother?

Tags: css

I have two arrows in CSS where one arrow is next to another like [in the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smx0d9kn/4/).

```css
.firstArrow {
  position: relative;
  background: rgb(0, 82, 48);
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  height: 50px;    float: left;
  width: 330px;
}
.firstArrow:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;

  background: linear-gradient(
    to right top,
    rgb(0, 82, 48) 50%,
    transparent 50%
  );
}
.firstArrow:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  bottom: 0;

  background: linear-gradient(
    to right bottom,
    rgb(0, 82, 48) 50%,
    transparent 50%
  );
}
.secondArrow {
  position: relative;
  background: rgb(0, 82, 48);
  margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;

  height: 50px;
  width: 330px;
}
.secondArrow:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right top,
    rgb(0, 82, 48) 50%,
    transparent 50%
  );
}
.secondArrow:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right bottom,
    rgb(0, 82, 48) 50%,
    transparent 50%
  );
}
.container {
    width: 700px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="firstArrow"></div>
  <div class="secondArrow"></div>
</div>
```

I wish it could look like on this image where one arrow goes in the next one. What's the way to do it?

[image]

Comment: You could just look at the source of the example page to see how they do it? There are probably many possible ways. Images with transparency, negative margins, funky border tricks to create triangles like this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: angular and typescript tag is unnecessary here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the element position is `absolute` why not add a `left` with negative value then specify the `z-index` of the each arrow.
Like this

BTW: change the color of the second arrow to see the overlapping of the first arrow.

```css
.firstArrow {
  position: relative;
  background: rgb(0, 82, 48);
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  width: 330px;
  z-index: 5;
}

.firstArrow:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient( to right top, rgb(0, 82, 48) 50%, transparent 50%);
}

.firstArrow:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient( to right bottom, rgb(0, 82, 48) 50%, transparent 50%);
}

.secondArrow {
  position: relative;
  background: rgb(100, 82, 48);
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 330px;
  left: -20px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.secondArrow:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient( to right top, rgb(0, 82, 48) 50%, transparent 50%);
}

.secondArrow:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient( to right bottom, rgb(0, 82, 48) 50%, transparent 50%);
}

.container {
  width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="firstArrow"></div>
  <div class="secondArrow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @GlobalArchitect Please close this question by accepting one of the solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a solution like the following:

```css
.arrow-container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 700px;
}
.arrow-container :not(:nth-child(1)) {
  margin-left: -25px;
}

.arrow {
  background: rgb(0, 82, 48);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
}
.arrow:after, .arrow:before {
  content: '';
  height: 50%;
  left: calc(100% - 1px);
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.arrow:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgb(0, 82, 48) 50%, transparent 50%);
  bottom: 0; 
}
.arrow:before {
  background: linear-gradient(to right top, rgb(0, 82, 48) 50%, transparent 50%);
  top: 0;
}

/** colorsets */
.arrow.active {
  background: rgb(0, 255, 0);  
}
.arrow.active:before {
  background: linear-gradient(to right top, rgb(0, 255, 0) 50%, transparent 50%);
}
.arrow.active:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgb(0, 255, 0) 50%, transparent 50%);
}

.arrow.other {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 0);  
}
.arrow.other:before {
  background: linear-gradient(to right top, rgb(255, 255, 0) 50%, transparent 50%);
}
.arrow.other:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgb(255, 255, 0) 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-container">
  <div class="arrow active">A</div>
  <div class="arrow other">B</div>
  <div class="arrow">C</div>
</div>
```